Compute legendre symbol
I am having trouble computing the following legendre/Jacobi symbol ($\frac{773}{2773}$). First, I do not know if 2773 or 773 are primer numbers. All the process I have made is:
$$
(\frac{773}{2773}) = (\frac{-1}{2773})(\frac{2000}{2773}) = (\frac{2000}{2773})
$$
But I am stuck here. Maybe I am missing a property? Any hint would be helpful, thank you.

Well, why not check for primality?  These numbers are small enough to check manually.

You'll need the law of quadratic reciprocity.

@lulu I guess but 2773 is 47*59 and that would take up some time to compute isnt there a faster way?

@AP you can only use it when both numbers are primer right?

When computing the Jacobi symbol, the formula that requires only that the two numbers are coprime and odd.

Few properties of Legendre symbol you need to know are that $(\frac{a}{p})(\frac{b}{p}) = (\frac{ab}{p})$ and the law of qudratic reciprocity. Thus, we have:
$(\frac{773}{2773}) = (\frac{2773}{773}) = (\frac{47}{773})(\frac{59}{773}) = (\frac{773}{47})(\frac{773}{59}) = (\frac{21}{47})(\frac{6}{59}) = (\frac{3}{47})(\frac{7}{47})(\frac{2}{59})(\frac{3}{59}) = (- \frac{47}{3})(- \frac{47}{7})(-1)(-\frac{59}{3}) = (\frac{2}{3})(\frac{5}{7})(\frac{2}{3}) = (-1)(-1)(-1) = \boxed{-1}$.
Calculating Legendre symbols needs a bit of practice.
